# OnTextChang for edittext in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 8 edit texts each allow only one character.when user enter something it automatically moves to next edit text. It's work fine by using onTextchanged.But i need to move backward also like when user enter back button it automatically moves to previous edit text and when enter something it move again next edit text. How i can do it.Please can any one help.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
editText_Pin1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
                if(editText_Pin1.getText().toString().length()==1) {    //size as per your requirement {
                    editText_Pin2.requestFocus();
                }

            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }
         });
```

Comment: You really should accept/upvote any answers you found helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            if(editText_Pin2.getText().toString().length()==1){//Here you will check the last editField which has lenght == 1 
                        editText_Pin1.requestFocus();
                        return false;//This will make sure your activity doesn't gets finished
            }
       }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Sorry . i don't want to use back button , i want to use x(cancel) on keyboard button.

Comment: My stock virtual keyboard doesn't even have a cancel button. I can use the back button to close/hide the virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by oveeriding the **onBackPressed** method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //check here which edittext has current focus,change the focus to previous edittext
    //you can use edittext array also.And also check if it is the first edittext then do nothing
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. [Activity.onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)
2. [Activity.onKeyDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) or [Activity.onKeyUp()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyUp%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)
3. [View.setOnKeyListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnKeyListener%28android.view.View.OnKeyListener%29) on each of your EditTexts
4. [View.onKeyPreIme()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyPreIme%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

I'd probably go with #1 or #3